# Can we change the "down for maintenance" page?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Right now the down for maintenance page looks like key mappings for some sort of video game.  Shouldn't we have a more relevant down for maintenance page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offline page wasn't *intended* to be site specific (was trying to show controls of arbitrary complexity) but it was interpreted that way.

I have changed it to a simple flat grid background now.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that what you see is a generic 'downtime page' that is common for all beta SE sites. Once we get out of beta then perhaps we will/can have our own customized page.